# Search functionality to search database tables in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have implemented the search functionality using the android search dialog to search multiple columns of a table using **LIKE** query, but search became slow as I have written a query in such a way that every time the text of each field(like the sample fields title, description category etc.)  will be searched.

```
title LIKE "---"OR description LIKE ''---"OR.....category LIKE "---"
OR location LIKE"---"to.
```

So is there any other way to speed up the functionality..

Comment: Can you show us some code? It'd make this easier for us.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the automatic suggestions feature that come up when you start typing the search keyword? If you'd be querying the database each time the users enters a key, that will be quite slow. You need to build the words index in advance.

See my reply with a code sample here:
[How to use QuickSearchBox in my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402525/how-to-use-quicksearchbox-in-my-android-application/3402614#3402614)